# pexpect version on vagrant box and on host is both 4.6.0, but when installing over ansible, 3.1 is the newest version

Tags: pip, ansible, vagrant

I was using ansible to install pexpect on both my vagrant box and also onto my host. When I installed pexpect onto both computers, the version is 4.6.0, but when using ansible to install using apt-get, the maximum version is only 3.1. The error message thrown is: `"Insufficient version of pexpect installed (3.1), this module requires pexpect>=3.3. Error was __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'echo'"}`How am I able to install pexpect in order to use the expect module for ansible?

The code for downloading pexpect is

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: no

 #can use sudo/sudo_user instead of become, but thats depreceated in       ansible 2.6 or later
  tasks:
  - name: download pip
    apt: name=python3-pip state=latest

  - name: update pexpect
    command: pip3 install pexpect
    command: pip3 install --upgrade pip3 
    command: pip3 install --upgrade pexpect
```

Comment: How is `prompt: "Server ip:"` relevant to the question?　How does `name: update pexpect` task with three `command` declarations work?　What user do you use to run Ansible with?　How other SO users can reproduce the problem ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: forgot to remove the server ip thing in this part,. Wouldn't using command 3 times execute 3 the three different commands. the pip3 install --upgrade command is included because I want to ensure that my version of pip3 is always the latest possible. I have pexpect being upgraded in hope that after upgrading pip, it will upgrade pexpect.

Comment: "*Wouldn't using command 3 times execute 3 the three different commands.*" ー of course not.

Answer (score 0):

Run a task per command and try to use Ansible `pip` module.

```
- name: Install Pexpect
  hosts: all
  become: True
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: False


  tasks:

  - name: download pip
    apt:
      name: python3-pip
      state: latest

  - name: Install Pexpect
    pip:
      name: pexpect
      state: latest

  - name: Upgrade pip - Force reinstall to the latest version
    pip:
      name: pip
      state: forcereinstall
```